# Solving parallel without GUI in batch mode not working as expected (Linux)

Tags: fluent

I'm currently trying to run my solutions in batch mode because in the future I'll be running simulations which I want to be done in the background.

I've tried to adapt the code from here: https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Fluent6/html/ug/node22.htm

Using some additional commands from here: https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/16.2.3/en-us/help/flu_gs/flu_ug_sec_startup_option.html

What I tried to do was:

```
fluent 3d -gr -t36 < inputfile >& outputfile &
```

Where the inputfile has no extension and has the following content:

```
; Read case file
rc CoolingChannelNoBatWall3D.cas
; Initialize the solution
/solve/initialize/initialize-flow
; Calculate 500 iterations
it 500
; Write case & data file
wcd CoolingChannelNoBatWall3DRes.cas
; Exit FLUENT
exit
yes
```

This starts the GUI, even though I tried to suppress it. After starting the GUI it does nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

```
fluent 3d -t 36 -g -i < inputfile.jou >& outputfile.jou &
```

Does not start the gui, but it's also quite hard to see if anything's really happening.

Comment: If you've found a solution to your problem, please add it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I will have to wait for a bit to mark it as accepted, but will do so in the future.

Comment: This is a software question (stackoverflow.SE),  not an engineering question

Comment: @CarlWitthoft This site has allowed some questions about Engineering software packages as they haven't received a warm welcome on SO or other SE sites.  My preference would be that the questions require some measure of engineering expertise in order to answer the question and not generalized troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was easier than expected, I didn't give the full file path to the fluent command:

`\ansys_inc\v192\fluent\bin\fluent 3d -t 36 -g -i < inputfile.jou >& outputfile.jou &`